# Are commas needed around "for example"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I need help in determining the proper use of commas.  It's an ongoing discussion in my creative writing group.

Which is correct:

- "Take, for example, my aversion to horror films," or
- "Take for example my aversion to horror films."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, yes, the commas are definitely needed.

This sentence is formed of two parts. "Take my aversion to horror films," is functionally separate from the fragment pointing out that it is an example.

The commas indicate that separation.

You could reword it, "As an example, take my aversion to horror films," which probably shows this separation more clearly.

Comment: Thanks, Rory.  Your thinking was the same as mine in every aspect, including rewriting the sentence.  I hope the others are as happy with the answer as I was.  I don't often get the chance to say, "I told you so."